# What is the alternative to using Facebook chat API now that Facebook will soon disable the XMPP API?

Tags: facebook, xmpp

Now that Facebook will be completely disabling the XMPP service soon, how do I get around this?  Will there be any possible way to send/receive messages in real-time?  Do I need to run my own XMPP server?

I assume there is still a way to do this or else desktop apps like Trillian would have to stop offering Facebook connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no other API that allows you to retrieve the user's chat information.

Comment: Yes, I realize that but it's not what I'm asking.  I'm asking how we will be able to send messages in the future.  Are you trying to tell me that it's completely going away?

Comment: Yes.  There may be an alternative in the future but right now you can't use the new API for chat messages.

Comment: So services like Trillian's Facebook chat will be shutting down?  Seems extremely counter-intuitive.

Comment: I don't know, I'm just telling you what is and is not possible at this time.